# Matplotlib Pyplot not plotting properly in a for loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, matplotlib, plot

tl;dr trying to create plots using for loop in Python 3 but it is resulting in weird inconsistent plots.

I am trying to create plots like Figure 2 of Fox et al. 2015 (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.1480.pdf). I have the different ion lines saved in a dictionary with their parameters saved as lists. For example,

```
DictIon = { 
'''The way this dictionary is defined is as follows: ion name: 
[wavelength, f-value, continuum lower 1, continuum higher 1, continuum lower 2, 
continuum higher 2, subplot x, subplot y, ion name x, ion name y]'''
'C II 1334': [1334.5323,.1278,-400,-200,300,500,0,0,-380,.2],
'Si II 1260': [1260.4221,1.007,-500,-370,300,500,2,0,-380,.15],
'Si II 1193': [1193.2897,0.4991,-500,-200,200,500,3,0,-380,.2]
}
```

In order to generate the plot, I have written the following code where at first I calculate the continuum of the absorption lines and then use data from a Voigt Profile algorithm that gives me the zval and bval that I use in the Voigt profile section of the code, and finally I combine these two and plot the values in appropriate subplots. The code is:

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(6, 2, sharex='col', sharey='row',figsize = (15,15))

for ion in DictIon:
    w0 = DictIon[ion][0] #Rest wavelength
    fv = DictIon[ion][1] #Oscillator strengh/f-value

    velocity = (wavelength-Lambda)/Lambda*c

    #Fit the continuum
    low1  = DictIon[ion][2]  #lower bound for continuum fit on the left side
    high1 = DictIon[ion][3]  #upper bound for continuum fit on the left side
    low2  = DictIon[ion][4]  #lower bound for continuum fit on the right side
    high2 = DictIon[ion][5]  #upper bound for continuum fit on the right side
    x1 = velocity[(velocity>=low1) & (velocity<=high1)]
    x2 = velocity[(velocity>=low2) & (velocity<=high2)]
    X = np.append(x1,x2)
    y1 = flux[(velocity>=low1) & (velocity<=high1)]
    y2 = flux[(velocity>=low2) & (velocity<=high2)]
    Y = np.append(y1,y2)
    Z = np.polyfit(X,Y,1)

    #Generate data to plot continuum
    xp = np.linspace(-500,501,len(flux[(velocity>=-500) & (velocity<=500)]))
    p = np.poly1d(Z)

    #Normalize flux
    norm_flux = flux[(velocity>=-500) & (velocity<=500)]/p(xp)

    #Create a line at y=1
    tmp1 = np.linspace(-500,500,10)
    tmp2 = np.full((1,10),1)[0]


    '''Generate Voigt Profile Fits'''
    #Initialize arrays
    vmod = (np.arange(npix+1)-(npix/pixsize))*pixsize #-npix to npix in steps of pix
    fmodraw = np.ndarray((npix+1)); fmodraw.fill(1.0)
    ncom = len(zval)+1

    fitn = 10**(logn); fitne = 10**(logn+elogn)-10**logn
    totcol=np.log10(np.sum(fitn))
    etotcol=np.sqrt(np.sum(elogn**2)) #strictly only true if independent

    #Set up arrays
    sigma=bval/np.sqrt(2.0); tau0=np.ndarray((ncom)); tauv=np.ndarray((ncom,npix))
    find=np.ndarray((ncom, npix)); sfind=np.ndarray((ncom, npix)) #smoothed

    #go from z to velocity
    v0=c*(zval-zmod) / (1.0+zmod); ev0=c*zvale  / (1.0+zmod) 
    bv=bval; ebv=bvale

    #generate models for each comp, where tau is Gaussian with velocity
    for k in range(0, ncom-1):
        tau0[k]=(1.497e-2*(10**logn[k])*(w0/1.0e8)*fv) / (bval[k]*1.0e5)
        for j in range(0, npix-1):
            tauv[k][j]=tau0[k]*np.exp((-1.0*(vmod[j]-v0[k])**2) / (2.0*sigma[k]**2))
            find[k][j]=np.exp(-1.0*tauv[k][j])

    #Transpose
    tauv = tauv.T
    find = find.T

    #Sum over components (pixel by pixel)
    tottauv=np.ndarray((npix+1))
    for j in range(0, npix-1):
        tottauv[j]=tauv[j,:].sum()

    fmodraw=np.exp(-1.0*tottauv)

    #create Gaussian kernel (smoothing function or LSF) 
    #created on 1 km/s grid with default FWHM=20.0 km/s (UVES), integral=1 
    fwhmins=20.0

    sigins=fwhmins/(1.414*1.665); nker=150 #NEED TO FIND NKER
    vt=np.arange(nker)-nker/2 #-75 to +75 in 1 km/s steps
    smfn=(1.0/(sigins*np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi)))*np.exp((-1.0*(vt**2))/(2.0*sigins**2))

    #convolve total and individual comps with LSF
    fmod = np.convolve(fmodraw, smfn, mode='same')

    axes[DictIon[ion][6]][DictIon[ion][7]].axis([-400,400,-.12,1.4])
    axes[DictIon[ion][6]][DictIon[ion][7]].xaxis.set_major_locator(xmajorLocator)
    axes[DictIon[ion][6]][DictIon[ion][7]].xaxis.set_major_formatter(xmajorFormatter)
    axes[DictIon[ion][6]][DictIon[ion][7]].xaxis.set_major_locator(xminorLocator)
        axes[DictIon[ion][6]][DictIon[ion][7]].yaxis.set_major_locator(ymajorLocator)
        axes[DictIon[ion][6]][DictIon[ion][7]].yaxis.set_major_locator(yminorLocator)

    axes[DictIon[ion][6]][DictIon[ion][7]].plot(vmod,fmod,'r', linewidth = 1.5)
    axes[DictIon[ion][6]][DictIon[ion][7]].plot(tmp1,tmp2,'k--')
    axes[DictIon[ion][6]][DictIon[ion][7]].step(velocity[(velocity>=-500) & (velocity<=500)],norm_flux,'k')
```

Instead of producing plots as Figure 2 of Fox et al. 2015, I am getting situations like this where the code will produce different results at different times when I run it:
[image: Fig1]
[image: Fig2]][2

Bottom line, I have tried to debug this for 3 days now and I am at a loss. I suspect that it may have something to do with how pyplot plots work in for loop and the fact that I am using a dictionary to loop through. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I am using Python 3.

Edit: 
Data available here:
zval,bval values: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxZ6b2fEZcGBX2ZTUEdDVHVWS0U/

velocity, flux values:

Si III 1206: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxZ6b2fEZcGBQXpmZ01kMDNHdk0/

Si IV 1393: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxZ6b2fEZcGBamkxVVA2dUY0Qjg/

Comment: Could you provide a set of sample data? (like **velocity**, **zval**, etc.)

Comment: I have added links to data in the edit

Comment: This could do with being re-asked with a minimum example, i.e., I presume the problem is about using matplotlib in a for loop, not about your complicated data-set etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a MWE of the operation you want to perform:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f, axes = plt.subplots(3, 2, sharex='col', sharey='row',figsize=(15,15))
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.)

data_dict = {'C II 1334': [1., 2.],
             'Si II 1260': [2., 3.],
             'Si II 1193': [3., 4.]}

for i, (key, value) in enumerate(data_dict.items()):

    print i, key, value    

    x = np.linspace(0, 100, 10)
    y0 = value[0] * x
    y1 = value[1] * x

    axes[i, 0].plot(x, y0, label=key)
    axes[i, 1].plot(x, y1, label=key)
    axes[i, 0].legend(loc="upper right")
    axes[i, 1].legend(loc="upper right")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Results in

[image]

I don't see any strange behaviour after invoking `plt` in a `for` loop over a `dict`.

I suggest you separate *data processing/calculations*, i.e. calculations of the scientific quantities of interest, from *plotting said data*.

Note that the ordering of the dictionary items isn't preserved - better to use a list or an ordered dictionary in my example.

Comment: I took your advice and turned it into a list and it seems to work now. The old code still doesn't work so I am guessing it probably has to do something with the unordered nature of dictionaries. Thanks for the tip!